# Set From Name to system generate emails

Tags: email, settings, config

Is it possible to set a from name to system generated emails - at the moment the from field is just the email address. Would be nice to be able to tidy that up if at all possible.

The control panel setting page at Admin > Email Configuration doesn't seem to allow this, but you can change the from address in the field titled 'Return email address for auto-generated emails'

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a little overkill for this one task, I am pretty sure you could use Postmaster for this. Just setup a "Send System Email" hook. Then you can define any from name/email you want.

More Information on Postmaster

https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster

Reference to the Send System Email hook.

https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/hooks/send-system-email

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but it *should* work:

```
"Your Name" <email@address.com>
```

Comment: Unfortunately EE will only allow a valid email address in that field. It errors when trying the format described here.

Comment: Boo, sorry - worth a try!